# Issue with Row Level Security in Supabase

Tags: sql, postgresql, backend, supabase

I have following tables.

```
create table
  public.records (
    id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid (),
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    content text null,
    patient_id uuid null,
    provider_id uuid null,
    constraint records_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint records_patient_id_fkey foreign key (patient_id) references patient_profiles (id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint records_provider_id_fkey foreign key (provider_id) references provider_profiles (id) on update cascade on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create table
  public.provider_patient (
    id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid (),
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    provider_id uuid null,
    patient_id uuid null,
    constraint provides_care_to_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint provider_patient_patient_id_fkey foreign key (patient_id) references patient_profiles (id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint provider_patient_provider_id_fkey foreign key (provider_id) references provider_profiles (id) on update cascade on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create table
  public.provider_profiles (
    id uuid not null,
    first_name text null,
    last_name text null,
    phone text null,
    constraint provider_profiles_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint provider_profiles_id_fkey foreign key (id) references auth.users (id) on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create table
  public.patient_profiles (
    id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid (),
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    first_name text null,
    last_name text null,
    phone text null,
    email text null,
    constraint patients_pkey primary key (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

Basically, my idea of relations was that provider can have many patients, patient can have many providers. Record can have one patient, patient can have many records.

I'm trying to make a RLS so when provider(user) queries the records table he get access only to the record of the patients he provides care for. I tried to first to do it in a SQL query, hardcoding auth.uid() and it works just fine:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  RECORDS
where
  'cec107e4-90bd-40e8-a233-d0b69a7d4c2c' in (
    select
      provider_id
    from
      provider_patient
    where
      patient_id = records.patient_id
  )
```

This returns properly filtered records for the particular user_id. But when i try to put it into RLS looking like this:

```
(
  auth.uid () IN (
    SELECT
      provider_patient.provider_id
    FROM
      provider_patient
    WHERE
      (provider_patient.patient_id = records.patient_id)
  )
)
```

it returns empty object. if i try to remove WHERE clause, just for the test, so it will return all the records, it returns still empty object.

Where's the catch, what am i doing wrong?

Tried writing RLS using EXISTS 1, but it seems that if the RLS makes request for other table(not the records table) it always returns empty.

Comment: There is no problem selecting from a different table in the RLS policy. You must have made some other mistake.

Comment: Pulling my hair out about what's wrong.  I can't even get it to return all records by omitting WHERE clause in rls, just for the test. It still returns empty.

Comment: Are you sure about what your auth.uid() is? Are you testing with right credentials? What is RLS like on provider_patient?

Comment: Oh, that was the culprit. I had an RLS policy on provider_patient, which denied all access to that table. I didn't realize that calls to other tables inside a rls policy are also ruled by RLS policies

Comment: For complex RLS rules like this, it is recommended to security definer function. Try converting your policy into a database function and try it out. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions#security-definer-vs-invoker

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your table structure properly and what you're trying to do with your RLS policy, what you have written will work, but is way more complicated than needed.

The following should be all you need:

```
(auth.uid() = provider_id)
```

However, as someone already commented, RLS policies from other tables still apply, even when RLS policies reference from other tables.

Still, my above policy statement should sidestep this, as I don't believe you actually need the foreign table reference.

Comment: Thanks, but i probably didn't name my columns correctly. `provider_id` in the records table should probably be named 'made_by_provider_id`, like it's which provider made this record, not which is caring for the patient.

Comment: AH. Okay, then yeah, that's not what you want. It would 100% be the RLS on the provider_patient table.

Comment: Yeah, it was. I didn't realize that if you do RLS for a table, and the RLS references some other table, you need to have proper RLS on that other table.